# App engine vs Compute engine : django project

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I am trying to transfer my current server from DO to GCP but not sure what to use between App engine and Compute engine.

Currently using:

- django 1.8
- postgres (connected using psycopg2)
- python 2.7

Thanks in advance!

Comment: DO == GCE == IaaS; Heroku == GAE == PaaS. If you are migrating from DO you are after GCE.

Comment: Thanks @PauloScardine. I just watched the difference between IaaS, PaaS and SaaS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DigitalOcean is IaaS (infrastructure as a service). I guess the corresponding offer from Google is Google Compute Engine, GCE.

Google App Engine is more like Heroku, a PaaS offer (platform as a service).

In practice, what is the difference between PaaS and IaaS?

- IaaS: if you have a competent system administrator in your team he probably will choose IaaS - because this kind of service will give him more control at the cost of more decisions and setup - but that is his work.
- PaaS: if you are willing to pay more (like double it) to avoid most of the management work and don't mind a more opinionated platform, than a PaaS may be the right product for you. You are a programmer and just want to deploy your code (and you are happy to pay an extra in order to avoid dealing with those dickheads in operations).

Probably you can find a more elegant comparison if you google for it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have a question, can I use postgresql in GCE without additional payment?

Comment: You probably can do anything you do using your Digital Ocean VPS, including running a local instance of PostgreSQL.